# Count the number of occurrences of a word

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files in a folder.example is below

1stFile:

```
Start New
 A 
 B 
 C 

Start Old
 A 
 A 
 A
```

So I want to count the number of A after we find the word `Start`.
So below is the output I am looking for

```
'Start New'  '1'
'Start Old'  '3'
```

I am new to powershell so finding it hard to put the design into code.any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are these actually [`.yaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) files? In that case, you better [threat them as `yaml`](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml)

Comment: No these are normal text files

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# Create a sample file.
@'
Start New
 A 
 B 
 C 

Start Old
 A 
 A 
 A 
'@ > test.txt

# Process the sample file.
$i = 0
(Get-Content -Raw test.txt) -split '(?m)^(Start .+)\r?\n' -ne '' |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($i++ % 2 -eq 0) { 
      $section = $_ 
    }
    else {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Section = $section
        Count = (($_ -split '\r?\n').Trim() -eq 'A').Count
      }
    }
  }
```

The above outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances with `.Section` and `.Count` properties, which render to the display as:

```
Section   Count
-------   -----
Start New     1
Start Old     3
```

Comment: How to write the object data to a output file @mklement0

Comment: @Android18: To save the for-display representation as shown in the answer to a text file, pipe to `Out-File`, but note that this format isn't meant for _programmatic_ processing. To save to a structured text format suitable for programmatic processing, pipe to, for instance, `Export-Csv`.

Comment: one more question what does this line do `Get-Content -Raw test.txt` (I understant Get-Content gets the content but what is with the -Raw)and why we need a sample file why we cannot pick the file directly from the path  @mklement0

Comment: @Android18: `Get-Content -Raw` reads a file _in full_, as a single, multi-line string, which is needed for the `-split`-based approach to work. The only purpose of the sample file (this applies to answers in general) is to _demonstrate that and how the solution works_. Of course, you would use the solution with _your_ files, so just replace `test.txt` with _your_ file name(s) / path(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with -File and -Wildcard (or -Regex) parameters and then group the output on the Label property to get the count.

```
$(
    switch -Wildcard -File .\text.txt {
        '*Start*' {
            $startLabel = $_
            continue
        }
        '*A*' {
            $obj = [pscustomobject]@{
                Label = $startLabel
                Match = $_
            }
            $obj
            continue
        }
    }
) | Group-Object Label -NoElement
```

```
Count Name
----- ----
    1 Start New
    3 Start Old
```

Comment: .I tried this I am getting this error `Cannot convert value to type "System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives+InternalPSCustomObject". Only core types are supported in this language mode`. so i used `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` which does not display the name and only gives the count

Comment: How to add this result into a output file